# Dividing Count from Query of count in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to essentially divide one count by a number I query from another table in SQL

```
MOVIECOUNT AS (
  SELECT COUNT(MS.MOVID) AS MOVCOUNT, MG.GENRE AS GENREPERCOUNT
  FROM MOVIESUCCESS MS
  INNER JOIN MOVIES_GENRES MG ON MG.MOVIE_ID = MS.movid 
  group by MG.GENRE
)

SELECT (MC.MOVCOUNT / COUNT(DG.MOVIE_ID))
FROM MOVIECOUNT MC, DIRECTORS_GENRES DG
WHERE MC.GENREPERCOUNT = DG.GENRE
GROUP BY DG.GENRE
```

I can't get the latter part to compile (the MOVIECOUNT works--just there for reference). The rest of the schema isn't that important, and I have the rest of the code working.
I'm essentially just trying to get the count I found in moviecount (which is done per genre) and divide that by the count of all movies of the same genre. Ideas? Oracle SQL

Comment: You probably need to use an aggregate function on the `MC.Movcount`.

Comment: can you explain @jnk

Comment: @AlexKornhauser In most RDBMS you need to use an aggregate on any expression not in the `GROUP BY`.  So try `MAX(MC.MovCount)`.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. I don't want the max of the counts. There are various counts of MC each correlating to a different genre. I want to divide each of these counts by the max in that specific genre

Comment: "can't get the latter part to compile" - what error(s) do you get?

Comment: Claims everything is an invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to compute each aggregate separately before joining them:

```
with mgc as (
  select
    mg.genre,
    count(*) as moviecount
  from
    moviesuccess ms
      inner join
    movies_genres mg
      on mg.movie_id = ms.movid
  group by
    mg.genre
), dgc as (
  select
    dg.genre,
    count(*) as directorcount
  from
    directors_genres dg
  group by
    dg.genre
) select
  mgc.genre,
  mgc.moviecount / dgc.directorcount
from
  mgc
    inner join
  dgc
    on mgc.genre = dgc.genre;
```

Comment: This works. No need to make mgc since that is already done in moviecount above

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the approach you are taking, you just have to be more careful with the aggregation:

```
WITH MOVIECOUNT AS (
      SELECT COUNT(MS.MOVID) AS MOVCOUNT, MG.GENRE AS GENREPERCOUNT
      FROM MOVIESUCCESS MS INNER JOIN
           MOVIES_GENRES MG
           ON MG.MOVIE_ID = MS.movid 
      group by MG.GENRE
    )
SELECT (MC.MOVCOUNT / COUNT(DG.MOVIE_ID))
FROM MOVIECOUNT MC JOIN
     DIRECTORS_GENRES DG
     ON MC.GENREPERCOUNT = DG.GENRE
GROUP BY MC.GENRE, MC.MOVCOUNT;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Says "Invalid Identifier DG.movie_id"

Comment: The `db.movie_id` is from your original query.  I have no way of knowing if that column is in that table.